# Why does python say that "f" or "q" is not defined?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a new programmer at python and was making a simple program that calculated the area but when
I tried to add a menu using the True ,else ,elif and if statments.

```
#Area.py#
print("The area and volume progam \n")
print("What do you want to do\n")
print("Find the area \n")
print("Find the volume \n")
print("Quit")
#valid_response= "True" 
while True:
        answer=(input("Press A, V, or Q : "))
        if answer in("A" ,"a"):
            find_area()
        elif answer in("V" ,"v"):
            find_volume()
        elif answer in("Q" ,"q"):
            break

        else:
            print("Invalid response")

#Area#
def find_area():
    length=input("What is the length?")
    width= input ("What is the width?")
    Area = int (length)* int(width)
    print ("The area is " + str (Area))

    f.close()
#Volume#
def find_volume():
    length= input ("What is the length?")
    width= input ("What is the width?")
    height= input("What is the height?")
    Volume= int (length) * int (width) * int (height)
    print ("The volume is " + str (Volume))

    f.close()
```

I'm probably missing something very simple; however, I haven't been able to find the answer on my own.

Comment: In `find_area` and `find_volume`, `f` is used, but is never defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling f.close() in `find_volume()` and `find_area()`.

The tutorial/documentation that you were working off of was likely calling f as part of a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) to write to a file, but you are not using a file in your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You call f.close() without initializing f.